# Solving non linear equations in Matlab

Tags: matlab

consider the following equations :

```
eqn1 =


    sin(t6)*(cos(t4)*sin(t1) + sin(t4)*(cos(t1)*sin(t2)*sin(t3) - cos(t1)*cos(t2)*cos(t3))) + cos(t6)*(cos(t5)*(sin(t1)*sin(t4) - cos(t4)*(cos(t1)*sin(t2)*sin(t3) - cos(t1)*cos(t2)*cos(t3))) - sin(t5)*(cos(t1)*cos(t2)*sin(t3) + cos(t1)*cos(t3)*sin(t2))) == 1


eqn2 =


    cos(t6)*(cos(t4)*sin(t1) + sin(t4)*(cos(t1)*sin(t2)*sin(t3) - cos(t1)*cos(t2)*cos(t3))) - sin(t6)*(cos(t5)*(sin(t1)*sin(t4) - cos(t4)*(cos(t1)*sin(t2)*sin(t3) - cos(t1)*cos(t2)*cos(t3))) - sin(t5)*(cos(t1)*cos(t2)*sin(t3) + cos(t1)*cos(t3)*sin(t2))) == 0


eqn3 =


    - sin(t5)*(sin(t1)*sin(t4) - cos(t4)*(cos(t1)*sin(t2)*sin(t3) - cos(t1)*cos(t2)*cos(t3))) - cos(t5)*(cos(t1)*cos(t2)*sin(t3) + cos(t1)*cos(t3)*sin(t2)) == 0


eqn4 =


    cos(t1)/100 + (19*cos(t1)*cos(t2))/100 - (21*cos(t1)*sin(t2)*sin(t3))/1000 + (21*cos(t1)*cos(t2)*cos(t3))/1000 - (219*cos(t1)*cos(t2)*sin(t3))/1000 - (219*cos(t1)*cos(t3)*sin(t2))/1000 == 619/1000


eqn5 =


    - sin(t6)*(cos(t1)*cos(t4) - sin(t4)*(sin(t1)*sin(t2)*sin(t3) - cos(t2)*cos(t3)*sin(t1))) - cos(t6)*(cos(t5)*(cos(t1)*sin(t4) + cos(t4)*(sin(t1)*sin(t2)*sin(t3) - cos(t2)*cos(t3)*sin(t1))) + sin(t5)*(cos(t2)*sin(t1)*sin(t3) + cos(t3)*sin(t1)*sin(t2))) == 0


eqn6 =


    sin(t6)*(cos(t5)*(cos(t1)*sin(t4) + cos(t4)*(sin(t1)*sin(t2)*sin(t3) - cos(t2)*cos(t3)*sin(t1))) + sin(t5)*(cos(t2)*sin(t1)*sin(t3) + cos(t3)*sin(t1)*sin(t2))) - cos(t6)*(cos(t1)*cos(t4) - sin(t4)*(sin(t1)*sin(t2)*sin(t3) - cos(t2)*cos(t3)*sin(t1))) == 1


eqn7 =


    sin(t5)*(cos(t1)*sin(t4) + cos(t4)*(sin(t1)*sin(t2)*sin(t3) - cos(t2)*cos(t3)*sin(t1))) - cos(t5)*(cos(t2)*sin(t1)*sin(t3) + cos(t3)*sin(t1)*sin(t2)) == 0


eqn8 =


    sin(t1)/100 + (19*cos(t2)*sin(t1))/100 - (219*cos(t2)*sin(t1)*sin(t3))/1000 - (219*cos(t3)*sin(t1)*sin(t2))/1000 - (21*sin(t1)*sin(t2)*sin(t3))/1000 + (21*cos(t2)*cos(t3)*sin(t1))/1000 == 0


eqn9 =


    sin(t4)*sin(t6)*(cos(t2)*sin(t3) + cos(t3)*sin(t2)) - cos(t6)*(sin(t5)*(cos(t2)*cos(t3) - sin(t2)*sin(t3)) + cos(t4)*cos(t5)*(cos(t2)*sin(t3) + cos(t3)*sin(t2))) == 0


eqn10 =


    sin(t6)*(sin(t5)*(cos(t2)*cos(t3) - sin(t2)*sin(t3)) + cos(t4)*cos(t5)*(cos(t2)*sin(t3) + cos(t3)*sin(t2))) + cos(t6)*sin(t4)*(cos(t2)*sin(t3) + cos(t3)*sin(t2)) == 0


eqn11 =


    cos(t4)*sin(t5)*(cos(t2)*sin(t3) + cos(t3)*sin(t2)) - cos(t5)*(cos(t2)*cos(t3) - sin(t2)*sin(t3)) == 1


eqn12 =


    (219*sin(t2)*sin(t3))/1000 - (219*cos(t2)*cos(t3))/1000 - (21*cos(t2)*sin(t3))/1000 - (21*cos(t3)*sin(t2))/1000 - (19*sin(t2))/100 == 261/1000
```

is there a function that can solve these equations ?

Comment: Did you look at Newton's method for nonlinear systems?

Comment: is there a function in matlab or should i do it on my own with pen and paper ?

Comment: I think that you can apply Newton's method with matlab. I don't have the information at hand though but if we google it, then it might become clear.

Comment: You might want to try a smaller system and make sure you can solve that first. Also you have 12 equations and 6 unknowns, which may suggest that no solution exists

Comment: I have 6 unknows, it does mean that i need at least 6 equations to solve

Comment: If you have more equations than unknowns then you may not be able to find a solution. Simplest example is `x=0`, `x=1`, 2 equations for one unknown, no solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fminsearch should do the trick.

https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html

Notice that solving non-linear equations may lead to local optima instead of global optima if the problem isn't convex. You can't really be sure to be globally optimal in many practical cases.

You would need to reformulate this to make it a minimization problem though.

f(x)=1 for example could be written as minimize abs(f(x)-1)